# java.net.URISyntaxException: Illegal character in query in AJAX POST call in jquery PHONEGAP

Tags: rest, jquery, cordova, http-post

I'm calling my Restful webservice POST method using below ajax call.

```
var inputData = '{"country","India"}'
$.ajax( {
        url : 'http://XXX.XXX.XXX.XX:XXXX/XXXX/services/ShopService/ShopSearchinfo',
        dataType : 'jsonp',
        data: inputData,
        cache: false,
        type: 'POST',
        mimeType: 'application/json', 
        contentType: 'application/json',
        error : function( thrownError) {
            alert('There is an error: '+ thrownError) ;


        },
        success : function(model) {
            trace('success') ;
            processResponse(model,successCallBack);
        }
    });
```

When request hits the server the server throwing below Error.

```
Caused by: java.net.URISyntaxException: Illegal character in query at index 119: http://XXX.XXX.XXX.XX:XXXX/XXXX/services/ShopService/ShopSearchinfo?callback=jQuery18209278033156879246_1359716402373&
{%22country%22,%22India%22}&_=1359716403257
```

FULL LOG IS :

The Full server Log is :

```
WARN org.jboss.resteasy.plugins.server.servlet.ServletContainerDispatcher - Failed to parse request.
java.lang.IllegalArgumentException
        at java.net.URI.create(URI.java:842)
        at org.jboss.resteasy.specimpl.UriInfoImpl.<init>(UriInfoImpl.java:70)
        at org.jboss.resteasy.plugins.server.servlet.ServletUtil.extractUriInfo(ServletUtil.java:72)
        at org.jboss.resteasy.plugins.server.servlet.ServletContainerDispatcher.service(ServletContainerDispatcher.java:178)
        at org.jboss.resteasy.plugins.server.servlet.HttpServletDispatcher.service(HttpServletDispatcher.java:48)
        at org.jboss.resteasy.plugins.server.servlet.HttpServletDispatcher.service(HttpServletDispatcher.java:43)
        at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:717)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:290)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:206)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:233)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:191)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:127)
        at org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:102)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:109)
        at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:293)
        at org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11AprProcessor.process(Http11AprProcessor.java:877)
        at org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11AprProtocol$Http11ConnectionHandler.process(Http11AprProtocol.java:594)
        at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.AprEndpoint$Worker.run(AprEndpoint.java:1675)
        at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:662)
Caused by: java.net.URISyntaxException: Illegal character in query at index 119: http://XXX.XXX.XXX.XX:XXXX/XXXX/services//ShopSearchinfo?callback=jQuery18209278033156879246_1359716402373&
{%22country%22,%22India%22}&_=1359716403257
        at java.net.URI$Parser.fail(URI.java:2809)
        at java.net.URI$Parser.checkChars(URI.java:2982)
        at java.net.URI$Parser.parseHierarchical(URI.java:3072)
        at java.net.URI$Parser.parse(URI.java:3014)
        at java.net.URI.<init>(URI.java:578)
        at java.net.URI.create(URI.java:840)
        ... 18 more
Feb 1, 2013 4:30:03 PM org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve invoke
SEVERE: Servlet.service() for servlet Resteasy threw exception
java.lang.NullPointerException
        at org.jboss.resteasy.plugins.server.servlet.HttpServletInputMessage.<init>(HttpServletInputMessage.java:60)
        at org.jboss.resteasy.plugins.server.servlet.HttpServletDispatcher.createHttpRequest(HttpServletDispatcher.java:64)
        at org.jboss.resteasy.plugins.server.servlet.HttpServletDispatcher.createResteasyHttpRequest(HttpServletDispatcher.java:53)
        at org.jboss.resteasy.plugins.server.servlet.ServletContainerDispatcher.service(ServletContainerDispatcher.java:188)
        at org.jboss.resteasy.plugins.server.servlet.HttpServletDispatcher.service(HttpServletDispatcher.java:48)
        at org.jboss.resteasy.plugins.server.servlet.HttpServletDispatcher.service(HttpServletDispatcher.java:43)
        at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:717)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:290)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:206)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:233)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:191)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:127)
        at org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:102)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:109)
        at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:293)
        at org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11AprProcessor.process(Http11AprProcessor.java:877)
        at org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11AprProtocol$Http11ConnectionHandler.process(Http11AprProtocol.java:594)
        at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.AprEndpoint$Worker.run(AprEndpoint.java:1675)
        at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:662)
```

---

FULL LOG IS :

The Full server Log is :

```
WARN org.jboss.resteasy.plugins.server.servlet.ServletContainerDispatcher - Failed to parse request.
java.lang.IllegalArgumentException
        at java.net.URI.create(URI.java:842)
        at org.jboss.resteasy.specimpl.UriInfoImpl.<init>(UriInfoImpl.java:70)
        at org.jboss.resteasy.plugins.server.servlet.ServletUtil.extractUriInfo(ServletUtil.java:72)
        at org.jboss.resteasy.plugins.server.servlet.ServletContainerDispatcher.service(ServletContainerDispatcher.java:178)
        at org.jboss.resteasy.plugins.server.servlet.HttpServletDispatcher.service(HttpServletDispatcher.java:48)
        at org.jboss.resteasy.plugins.server.servlet.HttpServletDispatcher.service(HttpServletDispatcher.java:43)
        at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:717)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:290)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:206)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:233)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:191)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:127)
        at org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:102)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:109)
        at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:293)
        at org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11AprProcessor.process(Http11AprProcessor.java:877)
        at org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11AprProtocol$Http11ConnectionHandler.process(Http11AprProtocol.java:594)
        at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.AprEndpoint$Worker.run(AprEndpoint.java:1675)
        at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:662)
Caused by: java.net.URISyntaxException: Illegal character in query at index 119: http://XXX.XXX.XXX.XX:XXXX/XXXX/services//ShopSearchinfo?callback=jQuery18209278033156879246_1359716402373&
{%22country%22,%22India%22}&_=1359716403257
        at java.net.URI$Parser.fail(URI.java:2809)
        at java.net.URI$Parser.checkChars(URI.java:2982)
        at java.net.URI$Parser.parseHierarchical(URI.java:3072)
        at java.net.URI$Parser.parse(URI.java:3014)
        at java.net.URI.<init>(URI.java:578)
        at java.net.URI.create(URI.java:840)
        ... 18 more
Feb 1, 2013 4:30:03 PM org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve invoke
SEVERE: Servlet.service() for servlet Resteasy threw exception
java.lang.NullPointerException
        at org.jboss.resteasy.plugins.server.servlet.HttpServletInputMessage.<init>(HttpServletInputMessage.java:60)
        at org.jboss.resteasy.plugins.server.servlet.HttpServletDispatcher.createHttpRequest(HttpServletDispatcher.java:64)
        at org.jboss.resteasy.plugins.server.servlet.HttpServletDispatcher.createResteasyHttpRequest(HttpServletDispatcher.java:53)
        at org.jboss.resteasy.plugins.server.servlet.ServletContainerDispatcher.service(ServletContainerDispatcher.java:188)
        at org.jboss.resteasy.plugins.server.servlet.HttpServletDispatcher.service(HttpServletDispatcher.java:48)
        at org.jboss.resteasy.plugins.server.servlet.HttpServletDispatcher.service(HttpServletDispatcher.java:43)
        at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:717)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:290)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:206)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:233)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:191)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:127)
        at org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:102)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:109)
        at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:293)
        at org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11AprProcessor.process(Http11AprProcessor.java:877)
        at org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11AprProtocol$Http11ConnectionHandler.process(Http11AprProtocol.java:594)
        at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.AprEndpoint$Worker.run(AprEndpoint.java:1675)
        at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:662)
```

Answer (score 0):

The URL is malformed, as it does not accept the character `{`. If you need them, escape them

Comment: Hi, Can u tell me How can i escape '{'

Comment: In your JavaScript, `escape(inputData)`